# Convert all array elements to a range in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array which is created as below:

```
im = plt.array(Image.open('Mean.png').convert('L'))
```

I have to convert all its values for an specified range. To do this, I have this function:

```
def translate(value, inputMin, inputMax, outputMin, outputMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = inputMax - inputMin
    rightSpan = outputMax - outputMin

    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - inputMin) / float(leftSpan)

    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    return outputMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)
```

In my specific problem I have to show this image contour:

```
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(im, origin='image', extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.savefig("ContourLevel2D.png")
```

But each grayscale value must be translate to the -1..1 range.
I know that I can do something like this:

```
CS = plt.contour(im/100, origin='image', extent=[-1, 1, -1, 1])
```

Which divide each element of *im* by *100*. 
But is there a similar/easy way to translate this values using the function I mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the operations inside of your `translate` function can be applied directly to your array:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

im = np.array(Image.open('Mean.png').convert('L'), dtype=float)

# Figure out how 'wide' each range is
leftSpan = inputMax - inputMin
rightSpan = outputMax - outputMin

# Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
imNormalized = (im - inputMin) / leftSpan

# Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
imTranslated = outputMin + (imScaled * rightSpan)
```

And you're all done, `im` now has the "span" desired.

This can be reduced slightly by doing the renormalizations *in place*, that is, don't make a separate array, just modify the current one.  Each time you rename the array, a copy is made.

```py
im = np.array(Image.open('Mean.png').convert('L'), dtype=float)

# normalize the input, in place 
im -= inputMin
im /= inputMax

# Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
im *= outputMax - outputMin
im += outputMin
```

Comment: this (doing them as separate array operations) would be faster than my answer, btw - vectorize just adds a loop over each point (on python, i think, so it's not as efficient as numpy array operations).

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to guess this is pyplot, and that the arrays are numpy arrays.

in which case:

```
import numpy as np
vtranslate = np.vectorize(translate, excluded=['inputMin', 'inputMax', 'outputMin', 'outputMax'])
plt.contour(vtranslate(im, imin, imax, omin, omax), ...)
```

but that's just a guess because i am reading docs for libraries i don't normally use, and you don't explain what libraries you're actually using...